How to get horizontal and vertical FoV of the picture taken by user in flutter?
I want to calculate the 2D area of the picture taken by user in flutter, therefore I wanted to use the horizontal distance, vertical and horizontal field of view of the picture taken. The horizontal distance I would put manually, but the rest, how can I retrieve in flutter? Is there any package for that? (lets say I dont want to use native codes)
Thank you,
